# Threshold for subject-area bronze badge doesn't match documentation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

This morning I was awarded the bronze badge for the [real-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-analysis) tag. According to [the description page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/66/real-analysis?userid=25554), this badge is awarded for “at least 100 total score for at least 20 answers in the real-analysis tag”.

I reached those thresholds several weeks ago but didn't receive the badge. At the time, I didn't mention it because I didn't care.

But I believe that the threshold is actually **25** answers, not 20, and that my posting of [my 25th answer with that tag, yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a25554%20[real-analysis]), is what triggered the award of the badge.

If this is correct, the description on the description page is inconsistent with the award, and at least one is incorrect, and should be fixed.

It's plausible that the description is correct and that nobody noticed the implementation error until now because it's much more easier to reach the 25-answer threshold before the 100-point threshold.

Comment: A possible explanation is that some of your answers are CW (aka Wiki). That has always been the explanation, when I've been late in getting a tag badge. Your profile page gives you this information. For example, when I hover the mouse cursor on top of the number 131 next to *real-analysis* on my profile page, it says "gave 18 non-wiki answers with a total score of 131". Even though a few characters to the right it reads "x19".

Comment: It seems to be as @Jyrki mentions.  While the page you quote from does not specify "non CW", the _Tag Badges_ section of [this page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges) does.

Comment: Mine does indeed say "Gave 20 non-wiki answers". That is surely the explanation.  Thank you!

Comment: Related: [Tag scores, tag badges, and CW answers](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/732/13653)

Answer (score 7):

Jykri Lahtonen points out that community wiki posts do not count towards the threshold of 20 answers; Arthur Fischer points out that this is documented in the "Tag Badges" section of the [Help Center > Badges](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges) page.

Hovering over the total score for [real-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-analysis) questions (currently 135) on [my profile page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/25554/mjd?tab=tags) raises a hoverbox that says:

> Asked 2 non-wiki questions with a total score of 25. Gave 20 non-wiki answers with a total score of 135.

So the answer is: the threshold is indeed 20 answers, as documented, but CW answers don't count.

Thank you, Jykri Lahtonen and Arthur Fischer.